# Rocketchat REST api reply to a particular message

Tags: rest, rocket.chat

I am looking for rest api to reply to a particular message in RocketChat. Rocketchat's REST Api documentation doesn't have anything about this. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I pass message.tmid as the message id for which i need to add the reply.

eg:

```
{msg: "test msg", rmid: <room_id>, tmid: <msg_id>}
```

Ref: https://docs.rocket.chat/api/rest-api/methods/chat/sendmessage

Answer (score 2):

```
{
    "msg": "method",
    "method": "sendMessage",
    "params": [{
        "_id": "xbWhuypufpcJn7LA5",
        "rid": "5aQQLBrqfNfnGGAha",
        "msg": "[ ]( {baseURL}group/{groupname}?msg={replyID}) {your_msg}"
    }],
    "id": "25"
}
```

Here is the quote example code.

If you want to create a new reply thread, you go with [tmid](https://developer.rocket.chat/reference/api/rest-api/endpoints/team-collaboration-endpoints/chat-endpoints/sendmessage)

If you just want to quote, send the msg in the above format

Comment: Yes I used tmid. 

{msg: "test msg", rmid: <room_id>, tmid: <msg_id>}

Implemented already. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Beu please mark it as an answer if it can help you. Thanks