# Rocketchat: how to respond to thread via API

Tags: api, chat, rocket.chat

**Rocketchat: how to respond to thread via API**

It is a very, very basic use case. I would like to send a message to a channel (this is easy to do via the postMessage API [[1]](https://developer.rocket.chat/reference/api/rest-api/endpoints/core-endpoints/chat-endpoints/postmessage)), and then continue writing messages in the thread of said message. However, I have not been able of finding anything in the documentation. Is it even possible?

For reference, someone asked the same question 19 months ago [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313605/rocketchat-rest-api-reply-to-a-particular-message). Sadly, the links to the documentation in the responses do not work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/api/v1/chat.sendMessage
message.tmid - optional argument to create the thread from message object
example of request body:

```
{
   "message": {
      "rid": "Xnb2kLD2Pnhdwe3RH", //room id
      "msg": "Sample message", //message text
      "tmid": "f6TRc4aouCzgCxKFb",//id of message the thread starts from
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Blatantly undocumented, but this works. I reverse-engineered the thing a while ago and forgot about this question. Thanks for answering!